# How can I show scrollbars on a PictureBox control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, picturebox, autoscroll

Sometimes, I have a picturebox lets say 100x100. But the image it will display is actually 100x400.

I don't want to increase the size of the picturebox itself. Instead, I would like to create a vertical scrollbar (or horizontal if needed).

I could not find a scrollbar in the toolbox, so I guess I have to code it. But, how?
And I still wonder if I didn't make a mistake and didn't see the scrollbar in the toolbox. My apologies then :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suppose you *could* add separate scrollbar controls and sync their `Scroll` events up with the offset at which the picture in the `PictureBox` is drawn, but that sounds like actual work. There's a better way.

1. **Add a `Panel` control to your form, and set its [`AutoScroll` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) to "True".** This will cause the control to automatically show scrollbars when it contains content that lies outside of its currently visible bounds. The .NET Framework will take care of everything for you under the covers, without you having to write a single line of code.
2. **Drag and drop your `PictureBox` control inside of the `Panel` control that you just added.** The `Panel` control will then detect that one of its child controls is larger than its visible area and show scrollbars, thanks to the `AutoScroll` property. When the user moves the scrollbars, the portion of the image in your `PictureBox` that is visible will be automatically adjusted. Magic.

(The reason you have to use a `Panel` control as a container is because `PictureBox` does not inherit directly from the [`ScrollableControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.aspx) base class, which is what provides the `AutoScroll` property.)

Comment: I had to set 'SizeMode' property of 'PictureBox' to 'AutoSize' to make this solution work

Comment: And I'd like to note that PictureBox cannot be docked in Panel.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it worked well.  But I noted that if the picturebox is docked in the panel, the picturebox is automatically set to the size of the parent panel, and can't be set larger (at least not in any way I could find).  This defeats the purpose of the technique.  So -- put the picturebox on the panel, but don't dock it, and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

There are no automatic scroll bars on a picture box, but you can add the VScrollBar (and HScrollBar) control to the form and handle the image scrolling manually  by redrawing it at a different offset each time the Scroll event is fired.

Comment: I'm way too lazy to do this. ;-)

Comment: Your way IS a lot faster, but you don't get to enjoy the frustration of figuring out which way to offset the image when it scrolls or when to move the scroll bars where.

Comment: If you need to base your image in center of the are are instead of top-left corner, then I think this is the only viable solution. Trick with Panel has its limitations – the image must grow from top-left corner.